# npm: Why is a version "0.1" invalid?

Tags: node.js, npm

I had to change the version of my npm app from 0.1 to 0.0.1 in order for npm not to do this.

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: invalid version: 0.1
npm ERR!     at validVersion (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modul
es/read-package-json/read-json.js:571:40)
npm ERR!     at final (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read
-package-json/read-json.js:323:23)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-packag
e-json/read-json.js:139:33
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/l
ib/async-map.js:48:11)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-packag
e-json/read-json.js:301:48
npm ERR!     at fs.js:207:20
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.5/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/lust/Documents/ply/dev-server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lust/Documents/ply/dev-server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

For completeness here's the working json

```
$ cat package.json
{
    "name": "ply",
    "description": "ply server for local dev testing deployments",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.x"
    }
}
```

version used to be "0.1" when it made the error.

Is this some sort of API/ABI compatibility versioning concept requiring 3 sets of version numbers? Why is the error message not more friendly w.r.t. this?

Comment: take a look at the `npm version` command. It allows you increment the semantic version based on major, minor, or patch levels. Examples: `npm version major`, `npm version minor`, `npm version patch`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes, this is required for [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), which is the versioning scheme npm packages use. Here's [the snippet from `npm help json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#version):

> Version must be parseable by [node-semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver), which is bundled with npm as a dependency. (`npm install semver` to use it yourself.)
>
> Here's how npm's semver implementation deviates from what's on semver.org:
>
> - Versions can start with "v"
> - A numeric item separated from the main three-number version by a hyphen will be interpreted as a "build" number, and will increase the version. But, if the tag is not a number separated by a hyphen, then it's treated as a pre-release tag, and is less than the version without a tag. So, `0.1.2-7 > 0.1.2-7-beta > 0.1.2-6 > 0.1.2 > 0.1.2beta`

Comment: cool. The error should just say something to the effect of "npm requires semantic versioning".

Comment: ++ for noting preferred handling of tagged-releases

Comment: @StevenLu I think this also should mention the version of semver that uses, currently is 2.0.0.

Answer (score 24):

Simple answer - use `0.1.0`

`0.1` will not work

Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

So yea, the short answer is "You need to use semantic versioning"

But the reasoning behind that is to provide a sensible, uniform package version to all users of npm. When getting a version number of an package, you have *some* level of confidence that the author understands semver and is employing it properly.