# Couldn't read dependencies npm install on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I got the annoying error when try to put dependencies via npm on windows. I gave correct name to package.json. Help me !

```
D:\sitenode>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: Invalid version: "0.1"
npm ERR!     at Object.module.exports.fixVersionField (C:\Program Files\nodejs\n
ode_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\node_modules\normalize-package-da
ta\lib\fixer.js:183:13)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [npm: Why is a version "0.1" invalid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887993/npm-why-is-a-version-0-1-invalid)

Comment: that is not duplicate ! I found it and I tried it but I didn't correct output. So

Comment: Could you explain where you tried to fix it?

Comment: copied another json file form online repo and replace with my json codes. And i tried to install again. but i got the same error. But when i install jsom file form online repo, it worked properly.

Comment: could you show your packages.json file ?? I think there's something wrong in json

Comment: '{
 "name" : "SiteWithNode",
 "version" : "v0.1",
 "private" : "true",
 "dependencies" : {
  "express" : "3.0.0alpha4",
  "jade" : "*",
  "stylus" : "*",
  "nib" : "*"
 }
}'

Comment: Your version string is not compliant with [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

Comment: I fix according [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887993/npm-why-is-a-version-0-1-invalid) that link but it show same errors !!

Comment: `install` `Couldn't read dependencies`
`npm ERR! Error: Invalid name: "React Learning"` so by reading here I found in my case name  `React Learning` is not correct. I removed white space it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to fix your string with semantic versioning. every version must be come with *.*.* style (three digits). so I changed your package.json and it's work

```
{ "name" : "SiteWithNode", 
  "version" : "0.0.1", 
  "private" : "true", 
  "dependencies" : { 
    "express" : "*.*.*", 
    "jade" : "*.*.*", 
    "stylus" : "*.*.*", 
    "nib" : "*.*.*" 
  } 
}
```

of course you might want to config (setup to fix certain versions due to compatibility). You might want to take a look at [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)