# how to workaround npm "Error: Invalid version: "0.1" BUG?

Tags: node.js, bash, awk, sed, npm

I am trying to build a nodejs package. When I run `npm install` I get `Error: Invalid version: "0.1` message and npm installation fails.

I tried to fix the error manually by replacing `"version": "0.1",` with `"version": "0.0.1",` in package.json files in modules directories but there are many modules that contain invalid `0.1` version. It's very hard to fix it manually.

Is there a simpler way to fix it?
Or maybe an awk, sed or other bash script that search for `package.json` files recursively and replace `"version": "0.1",` with `"version": "0.0.1",` help?

EDIT: I already checked out this thread [npm: Why is a version "0.1" invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887993/npm-why-is-a-version-0-1-invalid/) and lots of others prior to asking question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find "dir" -type f -name package.json -print |
xargs sed -i 's/"version": "0.1"/"version": "0.0.1"/'
```

should do what you describe. Replace "dir" with whatever your real starting directory is and test it first of course.

Comment: You are quite brave to bet that all those JSON files are formatted just the right way.

Comment: No, the script just give the OP what (s)he asked for, i.e. `an awk, sed or other bash script that search for package.json files recursively and replace "version": "0.1", with "version": "0.0.1"`. If that's NOT what's actually needed, as with all Q&A here, it's up to the OP to figure out what is.

Comment: @EdMorton
Your solution works but I failed to build the node package due to different errors. So I mark this question as fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq`:

```
jq '.version |= if . == "0.1" then "0.0.1" else . end' package.json
```

Since in-place editing is not yet available in released versions of `jq`, combining this with `find` to process all `package.json` files in a directory tree requires a subshell to redirect the `jq` output to a temporary file. For example:

```
find . -name package.json -exec bash -c "jq '.version |= if . == \"0.1\" then \"0.0.1\" else . end' {} > {}.new && mv {}.new {}" \;
```