# npm ERR! Invalid version: "1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, package.json

**QUESTION:**

When doing "node app" on my local machine, everything works.

But when I deploy my project to the Google App Engine, the instance is killed and I find the following error in my logs:

```
npm ERR! Invalid version: "1"
```

I looked at:

[npm: Why is a version "0.1" invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887993/npm-why-is-a-version-0-1-invalid)

[npm ERR! Invalid version: y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263870/npm-err-invalid-version-y)

[how to workaround npm "Error: Invalid version: "0.1" BUG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736059/how-to-workaround-npm-error-invalid-version-0-1-bug)

What is the mistake I need to correct ?

The deployment process started by `gcloud app deploy --version=deploy`

always ends with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.
```

Here is my package.json

---

**CODE:**

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Desc",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4",
    "npm": "4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "minify": "html-minifier --input-dir ./viewsCopy --output-dir ./views-minified --collapse-whitespace --html5 --minify-js true"
  },
  "author": "author",
  "license": "copyright",
  "dependencies": {
    "bad-words": "^1.5.1",
    "body-parser": "1.1*.1",
    "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
    "decimal.js": "^9.0.1",
    "ejs": "2.5.5",
    "events": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "express-session": "1.15.2",
    "express-validator": "3.2.0",
    "fast-crc32c": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "3.9.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "glob": "7.1.1",
    "helmet": "3.5.0",
    "html-minifier": "^3.5.0",
    "morgan": "1.8.1",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "4.0.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "raven": "^2.0.0",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.14.1",
    "uglify-js": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to provide the npm engine version?

Comment: npm engine version should have `^4.2.0` I guess

Comment: Tried updating npm? Are you sure you're in the directory of this particular package.json?

Comment: @TomaszBubała Yes. It wouldn't work locally otherwise, no ?

Comment: I thought maybe you're in a directory with other package.json containing "1" as a version. Your package.json seems fine to me

Comment: It is to do with engine property.

Comment: Can OP select an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In package.json the 'engine' properties allows you to block the node.js application running on versions of CLI tools which are unsupported.

You can either remove or modify the values. From quickly looking at the gcloud documentation they are using the latest stable from node.js (v9.4.0) which is bundled with npm v5.6.0. You could allow your application to run with existing versions and greater by adding the greater than character before the version.

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">6.9.4",
    "npm": ">4.2.0"
},
```

Answer (score 15):

in my case was

```
"version": "1"
```

I've edited to

```
"version": "1.0.0"
```

and it fixes.

Comment: I had `"version": "1.0"` and edited to `"version": "1.0.0"` and worked just fine, thanks

Comment: Your answer is **not** an answer to the question asked here. You have answered
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16887993).

Answer (score 8):

package.json -> version semantics may need to be like 1.0.0

https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning

Answer (score 4):

What fixed it for me was deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling with `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation provided over here for [node-semver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver#ranges) there may be an issue with the dependency packages versions being loaded

Double check these versions or remove all of these and then try, if it works then keep on adding one by one and ultimately when it stops working you know which version numbering is faulty

List is as follows which might be the possible suspects

```
"body-parser": "1.1*.1",
"fs": "0.0.1-security"
```

Comment: Sadly, that was not it. Nothing changed :/

Comment: Try removing all the dependencies from the list and then try if it works

Comment: it would obviously fail since the app engine instance needs to install the dependencies.

Comment: But you should get a different error rather than getting the error you have mentioned

Comment: same mistake: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace all dependency version with `*` , Same with npm version.
then run `npm install`.
I am not sure it will work or not but give it try.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove package-lock.json file. That will fix a problem.